# why is C not used so much in GUI programming?

Tags: c

i see that the C gui libraries are very less. Well the most prominent was GTK and alike. i dont see any prominence of C projects with GUI. Either C is not preferred for GUI. I see for like programming languages like C++, Java and Python, there are more GUI libraries and are more abundant. So what i ask is why does C not have a GUI lirary in surplus like others. Is it because of the absence of object orientation? mostly i see C used in console modes. Even in some system programming, other than that its either C++ or something else for GUI programming. Should one stop GUI design in C and go for other languages? I wish to know this in detail.

Comment: Lack of OOP, amongst many other limitations, is probably the main reason

Comment: ok now i see it. Maybe thats why object oriented programs became so popular. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I'll speak to the Windows API since that's the one I'm familiar with, but I suspect the others are the same. The Windows API is pure C! There's no need for a "library" to wrap it up, you can program to it directly.

The GUI components make for a good object hierarchy, so it's popular to package them in a C++ wrapper to make them easier to work with, but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: ok. i understand. i will check out the windows API.. somehow...

Answer (score 4):

Most GUI libraries work with objects (windows, buttons, widgets, frames, etc.) and properties and such. This is hard to emulate in C, while it is much easier in OO languages like C++, Delphi, C# etc. Note that the underlying APIs these frameworks use are often C, but much more awkward to use than the frameworks.

Comment: cool.. will look into it. So what is the framework in linux? like for most majority in most linux distros? has to be more C++ based. windows is more based on visual C++ right?

Comment: I don't know what the most polular framework for Linux is. I'd guess wxWidgets or Qt, but I don't usually program for Linux.

Comment: For native Windows, C+ is often used, although I prefer Delphi and its VCL.

Answer (score 2):

Since C doesn't natively support any kind of GUI calls, you're going to need
to rely on libraries provided by your system (such as the Windows API or the
Mac Toolbox (pre-OS X)) or a third party (GTK, QT).

Based on the very few times I've done it, I'd say that C is absolutely the
wrong tool for writing GUIs. Depending on the library, it can go from being
merely tedious to downright torture. You have memory management issues out
the wazoo, funky data structures, fairly complex pointer expressions
(something like *((**foo)->bar) wasn't uncommon) . You have to ratchet up
your definition of a "small" program by an order of magnitude.

Comment: there is no such thing as "GUI calls"

Comment: No language natively supports anything its all API calls written by the system or external libraries (a lot of which are written in C), also there are no "issues" with GUI programming in C, its uncommon because objects are better at handling such things. And how are pointers complex when you deal with them in C++ even when managing objects unless you're one of those who likes to drag and drop your GUI.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't include a gui library but neither does C++.

Most GUI libraries are written in C++ because they began in the mid-late 80s at about the same time that OOP became popular. If you are going to invent a new user interface paradigm you might as well use the new programming paradigm - the more buzz words the better.

There are some natural fits between OOP and GUIs, but you can write a GUI in pure C.

Answer (score 0):

C is a language, it's up to an operating system to provide an API to it's GUI interface.

Comment: And often these APIs are in C. But the frameworks built on top of the APIs often aren't. The advantages of OO (encapsulation, inheritance, etc.) play a big role here.